# PHP: strange function call function()()

Tags: php, function

It may be a very strange question, but I need to be sure if it really exists or not.
I've got the recruitment task for a PHP developer position with the following task:

> Make a **function** to **sum** two numbers **a** and **b** but it must be called as **sum(a)(b)**

I've never seen anything like that and can't find anything about functions like the above. The recruiter says it's not a typo; I'm confused.

Comment: Not sure about PHP, but that would be easy enough in JavaScript.  It would just mean that the `sum` function takes one argument and returns a function which itself takes on argument.  Can PHP return functions like JavaScript can?

Comment: The correct answer is: "PHP is not Javascript".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This assignment expects you to understand [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Basically, your `sum` function should return a function that accepts one argument and takes the other one from the surrounding closure:

```
// Javascript
function sum(a) { return function(b) { return a + b  } }
sum(3)(4) // 7
```

You can do almost the same in php:

```
function sum($a) {
    return function($b) use($a) {
        return $a + $b;
    };
}
```

but since php doesn't allow two calls in a row, you'll need a temporary variable:

```
$add3 = sum(3);
print $add3(4); // 7
```

This

```
 sum(3)(4);
```

is not possible in php (as of 5.5) - parse error.

I'm pretty sure your interviewer actually means javascript, not php (note the lack of `$`'s in the assignment).